Romantic comedy movie
Chubby man jogging in park, gray sweatshirt and pants, white sweatband on head.  Has a watch on that keeps track of his heart rate.  While jogging in park, a friend of his is walking next to him, as they are talking, his watch starts beeping, the chubby man ignores it, and keeps talking with friend.  The beeping gets faster and chubby man ends up not being able to breath, and scene shoots to ambulance ride with the ambulance tech knowing the chubby man by name, which surprises the friend that went along with him in the ambulance.

Sounds like the money pit with Tom Hanks and Shelley Long

Hi. Do you remember the year? The country\language? The general plot and other scenes?

Thank you thank you thank you!!!  It was the Money Pit!!!!  You rock!!!

The movie you are looking for is The Money Pit from 1986 starring Tom Hanks and Shelley Long.

Walter Fielding and Anna Crowley have to start looking for a new
  house- but there's not much they can afford! This soon changes when
  they meet a lonely old con artist who sells them a beautiful mansion
  at a ridiculously low price. Only there's a catch. The second they
  move into the house it falls apart, starting with the stairway
  collapsing to the bathtub falling through the floor to eventually the
  chimney falling into the house! Finally, they have to renovate the
  house before the frame collapses but the renovations also prove to be
  a disaster.

The scene that you're referring to is Walter Fielding (Hanks) speaking to his realtor Jack 
Schnittman (Josh Mostel) about purchasing a home.  Schnittman has recently taken up jogging for his health and always seems to be taken to the hospital for over exertion.
